# IQueryable returning empty result after performing LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, azure-cosmosdb, iqueryable

I'm using the Microsoft.Azure.Documents.IDocumentClient interface to access CosmosDB documents, using the CreateDocumentQuery method.

When I run the code without including any linq queries, I get all of my documents with no problem:

```
client.CreateDocumentQuery<MyDatabaseClass>(CollectionUri, options)
      .ToList()
```

I want to get the ID of the documents so I Try the following code:

```
client.CreateDocumentQuery<MyDatabaseClass>(CollectionUri, options)
      .Select(doc => doc.Id)
      .ToList()
```

And this returns 0 results.

If I switch it around and enumerate the IQueryable before performing the query it works fine, but as I understand this stuff (Though there's a good chance I don't) that's less performant.

```
client.CreateDocumentQuery<MyDatabaseClass>(CollectionUri, options)
      .ToList()
      .Select(doc => doc.Id)
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong with the queryable for this to happen? (Note, the above is a simplified version of what I'm actually trying to achieve, but the issue still occurs even at this level).

Databse Item Schema:

```
{
  "type": "",
  "view": {
    "date": "",
    "paths": {}
  },
  "id": "",
  "viewId": ""
  "version": "",
  "_rid": "",
  "_self": "",
  "_etag": "",
  "_attachments": "",
  "_ts": ""
}
```

Class:

```
public string Id{ get; private set; }

public string ViewId { get; private set; }

public string Version { get; private set; }

public abstract string Type { get; }
```

Comment: I don't know this database but queries linqs can't convert all queries to the database language.
In SQL Server it is common to show warnings like "it was not possible to convert the query." And the code generates several SQL queries to make a single Linq query (probably inefficient).

So I imagine that this problem is happening in your case. It cannot filter in the language of your DB. But if you use ToList () in which all data is loaded into memory, it is possible to filter. But inefficient.
Try reading the db documentation to verify the problem.

Comment: There is clearly a problem with a query evaluation on server side. Can you provide your real query and some samples of database entities which are related to it?

Comment: @Paulo, I'm using cosmosDB & IDocumentClient which, as documented here should be able to use LINQ. However there is a SQL options so I'll give that a go. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.idocumentclient.createdocumentquery?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: @Plusce, the simple select statement above is a real query that won't work. Ther database Items look like this:`{
    "type": "",
    "view": {
        "date": "",
        "paths": {        }
    },
    "id": "",
    "version": "",
    "_rid": "",
    "_self": "",
    "_etag": "",
    "_attachments": "",
    "_ts": 
}`

Comment: Please edit your question and add the database item properly formatted to your question. Could you also give us the `IQueryable<...>` that CreateDocumentQuery<MyDatabaseClass>(...) returns?

Comment: I tried your code, and it works fine on my side(sdk version is 2.11.6.0):


`IDocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(EndPoint), Key);
  FeedOptions options = new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true };
  List<string> ids = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Document>(CollectionUri, options).Select(doc => doc.Id).ToList();
            foreach(var id in ids)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(id);
            }`

Answer (score 0):

If you're not specifically tied to LINQ for query construction, consider using the `QueryDefinition` class in the .NET SDK to define your queries in SQL syntax to run within Cosmos. Ideally any filtering or shaping is done by the query, not within code on the result.

See [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Samples/Usage/ItemManagement/Program.cs#L346) for a good starting point. For selecting ID only:

```
QueryDefinition query = new QueryDefinition("select c.id from c");

// Provide query to container.GetItemQueryIterator<MyDatabaseClass>()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this issue using the [CreateDocumentQuery overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.idocumentclient.createdocumentquery?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_IDocumentClient_CreateDocumentQuery_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Documents_SqlQuerySpec_Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_FeedOptions_)  that takes a SQL query instead of using LINQ.